How to setvalue of a textarea instant and call api after 2 second for efficiency
I've a textarea and I'd like to udpate text area text instantly as user enter text but I don't like to hit api after every keystroke for obvious reason for efficiency.
I've tried to use debounce function but function is getting triggered as many times after every keystroke but with some delay that I've added in debounce
codesandbox link
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  function callAPI(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    // CALL API HERE
  }

  const debouncedAPI = _.debounce(callAPI, 2000);

  function onChangeText(e) {
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(`value inside onChangeText: ${value}`);
    setText(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea
        name="textarea"
        id=""
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChangeText(e); // Update the state
          debouncedAPI(e.target.value); // Call the debounced API with the latest value
        }}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
}


It happens because you call your debouncedAPI function in the onChange function. Which means, you call it after every single change. To solve this issue, you need to change your debounce mechanism that delays the API call until the user stops typing for a specified duration. Below is an example using a custom useDebounce hook to handle the debouncing logic efficiently:
export function useDebounce(value, delay = 500) {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a timeout to update the debounced value after the specified delay
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delay);

    // Cleanup function to clear the timeout if value changes before delay period
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [value, delay]); // Only re-run effect if value or delay changes

  return debouncedValue;
}

The useDebounce hook is designed to delay the update of a value for a specified period of time (delay) to reduce the frequency of an action (e.g., API requests or event triggering). It "debounces" rapid changes to the value, ensuring that updates happen only after the user stops interacting for the given delay period.
export function DebouncedInput() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const debouncedValue = useDebounce(inputValue, 500);

  useEffect(() => {
     if (debouncedValue) {
       // Call your API with the debounced value
       console.log('API call with value:', debouncedValue);
     }
  }, [debouncedValue]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={inputValue}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="search"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

Now provides an input (or textarea) where users can type freely, but instead of triggering an action (like an API call) on every keystroke, it waits for a specified delay after the user stops typing before making the API call.
